# when I change combobox field, I need to put the correc value in other field for a view

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino

My problem is I have to create a form using Domino Designer, which contains a field with a combobox. That combobox has a list of a column in a view. Next to this field is a another that was the price of the product selected in the combobox, and this price came for the same view.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything? Or are you expecting someone to do your work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The second field must be computed, and you need to use the [@DbLookup function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DBLOOKUP_NOTES_DATABASES.html) in it's formula. You also need to set the property [Refresh fields on keyword change](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FIELD_PROPERTIES_BOX_CONTROL_TAB.html) for the combobox field.